# Strtoul Returns Wrong Output in Toy JVM Parser

Tags: java, c, parsing, jvm, strtoul

I am trying to program a simple bit JVM with C. After reading the .class file with hex, I am trying to parse this file.

```
char *get_bytecode(const char *filename) {
    FILE *fileptr = fopen(filename, "rb");
    if (!fileptr) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: could not open file %s\n", filename);
        return NULL;
    }
    char *buffer = malloc(1);
    buffer[0] = '\0';
    unsigned char byte;
    while(fread(&byte, sizeof(byte), 1, fileptr) == 1) {
        char *temp = malloc(3);
        sprintf(temp, "%02x", byte);
        buffer = realloc(buffer, strlen(buffer) + strlen(temp) + 1);
        strcat(buffer, temp);
        free(temp);
    }
    fclose(fileptr);
    return buffer;
}
```

There is no problem with the above function that I occured. After that, I wrote a function to parse the bytecode I received:

```
classfile parse_class(const char *bytecode_hex) {
    classfile classfile;
    memset(&classfile, 0, sizeof(classfile));
    char *endptr;
    classfile.magic = strtoul(bytecode_hex, &endptr, 16);
    printf("Magic: %08X\n", classfile.magic);
    classfile.minor = (uint16_t)strtoul(endptr, &endptr, 16);
    printf("Minor: %04X\n", classfile.minor);
    classfile.major = (uint16_t)strtoul(endptr, NULL, 16);
    printf("Major: %04X\n", classfile.major);
    return classfile;
}
```

I guess the problem is here because I am getting an output like this:

```
Magic: FFFFFFFF
Minor: 0000
Major: 0000
```

but the expected output should be like this:

```
Magic: CAFEBABE 
Minor: 0000
Major: 0056
```

I couldn't understand exactly what caused the problem. Thank you in advance for any constructive comments.

Comment: You should `printf("%s\n", bytecode_hex)` in the `parse_class()` function. `strtoul()` returns `ULONG_MAX` if it is out of range.

Comment: Your `realloc(buffer, strlen(buffer), ...)` looks dubious. Can the bytecode contain zero bytes? Better to maintain the current length of your buffer in a variable, and double it each time you realloc.

Comment: Procees the bytes first, not hex codes. Use hex only to print the output.

Comment: The classic way to build an incoming value isn't with all that malarkey, but to multiply an accumulator by the base and add the incoming byte.

Comment: Some docs: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-4.html and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_class_file You'll have to read in the data as _binary_ bytes and store them on field-by-field basis. This could be a C struct as is, _except_ for variable arrays _embedded_ in the struct (which C does _not_ have): `u2 constant_pool_count; cp_info constant_pool[constant_pool_count-1];` In C, we'd need a pointer: `u2 constant_pool_count; cp_info *constant_pool;  // [constant_pool_count-1]` Similar for `interfaces*`, `fields*`, `methods*` and `attributes*`

Comment: To start, I'd create two functions: `classfile_load` and `classfile_store`. The first populates the above [C] struct from the class file. The second serializes it to an output file. Both files should now _match_ byte-for-byte. Also, you could have a `classfile_print` that prints out the struct in human readable format (e.g.) `printf("magic=%4.4X\n",ptr->magic);` This proves that you read it in correctly, accounting for byte-endianess, etc.

Comment: Don’t you feel something’s weird about converting data to a hex dump and parsing it back to data?

Answer (score 0):

Did you look at your `bytecode_hex` string? You are printing a long string of hexadecimal digits. The first `strtoul()` processes it in its entirely, overflowing, and so returning `0xffffffff`. (Or perhaps `0xffffffffffffffff`, since you are only printing the low eight digits.) The next two `strtoul()` calls see no hex digits, and so return 0.

You need to put in spaces for where you want the `strtoul()` to stop. Otherwise it has no clue how to parse a string of nothing but hex digits.

Also, it makes no sense to convert the byte codes to hex, and then back to binary. Just process the byte codes.